# View does not display updated values when using HTML helpers in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have such a problem. I change my models fields in controller but doesn't see the changes.

Here are the parts of code :

this is view
Index.aspx

```
<%Html.BeginForm("Index", "First");%>
<p>        
    <%=Html.TextBox("Title") %>
</p>
<p>        
    <%=Html.TextBox("Price") %>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<%Html.EndForm();%>
```

this is controller:

FirstController.cs

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyModel());
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ViewResult Index(MyModel k)
    {
        k.Title = "Title";
        return View(k);
    }
```

and this is model:

MyModel.cs

public class MyModel
    {

```
    public String Title { get; set; }

    public Decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

when I change "Title" text box in controller I don't see changes in view

```
public ViewResult Index(MyModel k)
    {

        k.Title = "Title";
        return View(k);

    }
```

text box keep its value before submit.
Is there any mistake in my code.

This problem doesn't appear when I use html standart input tag instead of Html.TextBox:

```
input type="text" id="Title" name="Title" value="<%=Model.Title %>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ViewResult Index(MyModel k)
    {
        ModelState.Clear(); 
        k.Title = "Title";
        return View(k);
    }
```

Have you tried to add ModelState.Clear() as in the above sample?
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have such a problem, but I think that we both don't understand MVC application lifecycle.
Let wait other answers

Answer (score 0):

you should do it like this:

```
<%Html.BeginForm("Index", "First");%>
<p>        
    <%=Html.TextBox("Title",Model.Title) %>
</p>
<p>        
    <%=Html.TextBox("Price",Model.Price) %>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<%Html.EndForm();%>
```

The Html.TextBox() have a overwrite version take object value arg to populate the text value!

Comment: I think the OP has the issue when he posts to the action. A default value is only set, when there is no value for Title in the post.

Comment: just have a try on my sugesstion!BTW i don't understander what did you mean above.